# Should I escape underscores inside code snippets in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Usually vim and some other editors (with resource plugins) mark a warning when I have the underscore `_` character without being escaped in any form of text. The same kind of warning shows up if the character is inside a code snippet.

For instance, if I take example.md:

````
For example:
```
some_text_here
```
````

The `_` appear with a warning mark.

Is it a problem with the editor's plugin rules, or according to Markdown syntax rules the `_` char should always be escaped (even inside code snippets)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a problem with the editor's syntax highlighting.

[No markdown implementation will convert this to emphasis](https://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%60%60%60%0Asome_text_here%0A%60%60%60).